# Word: Different levels of headings with different formatting

Tags: microsoft-word

I feel dumb for asking, but I've wasted so much time already on this: I just want to summarize some things so it's easier for me to study. To structure my document, I'd like to use different levels of headings. level1 headings should have the biggest font size and a different color from level2 headings; same goes with respect to level3 headings.

I formatted some stuff under "Styles" (see picture). Now I want that when my level1 heading is "2.", my level2 heading is "2.x". Instead, as you can see, it's "1.x".

Less importantly: under References < Add Text you can assign the level of text for the table of contents. Can I assign this automatically to my user-defined styles (so level1 heading is automatically "Level 1", level2 heading is "Level 2" and so on)?

[image]

Comment: *I want that when my level1 heading is "2.", my level2 heading is "2.x". Instead, as you can see, it's "1.x".*... This is unclear. Are you saying you can't assign the style to the text? Or that you want Word to automatically assign the style based on the outline level you are at in the document?

Comment: Your best bet is to start at Shauna Kelly's site with some reading on how to setup section numbering. Ignore the semi-useful things in Word Help. https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html?p=1768 Use the Multi-Levl List dialog to correctly configure the section headings  numbering styles and indenting. Then use the Paragraph and Font dialogs to set the paragraph spacing and the colors and size, respectively. Don't mess with the numbering or indents using any dialog other than the Multi-Level List dialog.